# Highcharts yAxis plotlines not showing on 'line' chart type

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts, and can't figure out why my yAxis plotlines display just fine for column and area charts, but not for line (or spline) charts.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem -- the only difference between these is the chart type:

https://jsfiddle.net/x9hLmp5v/

Inspecting the svg for the line chart, you'll see that the paths for plotlines are not getting set (please scroll to the right to see the values):

```
<g class="highcharts-plot-lines-5" data-z-index="5">
  <path fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-line " stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="16,6"></path>
  <path fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-line " stroke="green" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="10,30"></path>
</g>
```

Whereas they are normal for the other two chart types:

```
<g class="highcharts-plot-lines-5" data-z-index="5">
  <path fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-line " stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="16,6" d="M 78 225 L 606 225"></path>
  <path fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-line " stroke="green" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="10,30" d="M 78 272 L 606 272"></path>
</g>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that column chart renders column from 0 to set value, meanwhile, the line series render point as a set value and the yAxis range is different than for the column chart, so the plotLine value in your case is out of the yAxis range for the line series.

You can change the `yAxis.min` value to change this range and see the `plotLines`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/957c4jmk/

```
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {},
    "type": "linear",
    "startOnTick": false,
    "endOnTick": false,
    "min": 0,
    "max": null,
    "plotLines": [
      {
        "color": "#FF0000",
        "dashStyle": "LongDash",
        "width": 2,
        "value": 1200,
        "zIndex": 5
      },
      {
        "color": "green",
        "dashStyle": "Dot",
        "width": 10,
        "value": 800,
        "zIndex": 5
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thank you -- that never occurred to me!